# Use Devextreme js Widget in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, devextreme

I'm trying to find a way to use Devextreme [RadioGroup](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Widgets/RadioGroup/Overview/) js widget with  ASP.NET Core.

I've created this simple View:

```
<form asp-action="SelectSourceData" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rg-mode">Please Choose Migration Mode</label>
        <div id="rg-mode"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Proceed</button>
</form>

@section Scripts {
<script>

    $(function () {
        $("#rg-mode").dxRadioGroup({
            dataSource: modes,
            displayExpr: "text",
            valueExpr: "val",
            value: "by-org"
        })
    });

    var modes = [
        { text: "By Organisation", val: "by-org" },
        { text: "By Contract Type", val: "by-contr" },
        { text: "By Employee", val: "by-emp" },
        { text: "Mixed Mode", val: "mm" }
    ];

</script>
}
```

When user presses **Proceed** button `SelectSourceData` action method is invoked:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult SelectSourceData(string val)
{
    // get selected value here ... ?

    return View();
}
```

My question is: is it possible to somehow obtain the value selected in `dxRadioGroup` widget?

Comment: You don't have any form controls, so there is nothing to submit

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can I somehow use the RadioGroup widget as a form control?

Comment: Looking at the [demo](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/RadioGroup/Overview/jQuery/Light/), on option might be to handle the `onValueChanged` event to set the value of a hidden input that gets submitted

Comment: In fact, looking at the asp.net-core-mvc [demos](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/RadioGroup/Overview/NetCore/Light/) - those appear to have a hidden input generated by `@(Html.DevExtreme().RadioGroup()....)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your remarks, they helped me find a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Stephen's advice I added a hidden input field:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input id="hdnMode" name="mode" type="hidden" value="by-org" class="form-control" />
    <label for="rg-mode">Please Choose Migration Mode</label>
    <div id="rg-mode"></div>
</div>
```

and registered a handling function for value changed event:

```jquery
$(function () {
    $("#rg-mode").dxRadioGroup({
        dataSource: modes,
        displayExpr: "text",
        valueExpr: "val",
        value: "by-org",

        onValueChanged: function (e) {
            var previousValue = e.previousValue;
            var newValue = e.value;

            // Event handling commands go here
            $("#hdnMode").val(newValue);
        }
    })
});
```

The action method now correctly obtains the value submitted by the form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult SelectSourceData(string mode)
{
    // mode argument successfully set to submitted value
    var t = mode;

    ....
```